# iOS - How to access custom cell when handle button event in that cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have a custom cell, and in this custom cell I have a button and a label:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ListCell : UITableViewCell{

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* buttonContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* detailContent;

@end
```

When I handle button's click event:

```
- (IBAction)expandListCell:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)button.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    cell.detailContent.text = @"FALSE"; // It throw an exception   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"listCell";
    ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
    cell.buttonContent.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

It throw an exception when I try to access any item from my custom cell(ListCell):

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView detailContent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8887ca0'
```

I think the way I got custom cell is wrong. Anyone know how to get it properly?
Thank in advance

Comment: Please post the cellForRowAtIndexPath: too.

Comment: Question 1: Do you have a `@synthesize` in your custom cell implementation? Question 2: Why are you trying to get the cell in the first place - your button should be calling a method on the cell to tell it to change the text. Your button code should not be directly accessing the cell contents.

Comment: @Mat: I have add cellForRowAtIndexPath. Nick Bull: 1,Yes I have synthesize. 2, I really need to access cell when button is clicked, the code I posted is simplified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you sure you are calling the right class?
are you sure the super view class of your button is a ListCell class?

try to check this :

```
    // (...)
    ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)button.superview;
    if ([cell.class isSubclassOfClass:[ListCell class]]) {
        ///// just a check for indexPath: /////
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"current indexPath: %@", indexPath );
        ///////////// END CHECK ///////////////
        cell.detailContent.text = @"FALSE"; 
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NOT THE RIGHT CLASS!!!");
    }
```

Comment: what the line **`NSIndexPath *indecPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];`** dose there? may be it gives warning about unused variable indexpath

Comment: @meronix: yes u're right, it's not ListCell nor UITableViewCell. ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)button.superview.superview; is the right way to get cell. Thank for your answer

Comment: @Claric PWI: yes, you're right, it was there just for check… i pasted it from my project, now i re-add a log to make it sense with an edit

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it sorry not getting your question properly what you can do is just assign a teg to your label view before add it to the cell and then at the time of retrive just use

```
UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
```

and set the text for label

Comment: detailContent is a custom property label

Comment: Probably detailContent is a property of ListCell.